# Flutter: How to disable lazy loading in Syncfusion pdf viewer

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion, viewer

You can view the problem is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1feCtoTgpo38qx27fwGhGaIkgLS07eYiq/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please keep in mind that Syncfusion pub packages are **not** open source.  They can be freely used under some limited conditions of their commercial license, but beware of exceeding those limits, as you may end up with a financial liability.

Answer (score 2):

Currently we do not have support for avoiding lazy loading in SfPdfViewer. When we disable the lazy loading, it causes the  memory and performance related issues. Please share your complete requirement for disable the lazy loading in SfPdfViewer.

Comment: Thanks. I no longer use the syncfusion package. Because it is a commercial package